# How to get the data dependency information from llvm IR?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm

For example, the code below

```
  %div = sdiv i32 %add, %36
  %38 = trunc i64 %indvars.iv.next18 to i32
  %mul11 = mul nsw i32 %div, %38
```

The fist and third instruction may be a data dependency because the first instruction computes `%div` and the third one need `%div`.

Similarly, `%38` computed at second instruction, and the third instruction needs it.

Are there any tools or llvm `opt` commands can get the information about data dependency?

I tried `opt -enable-new-pm=0 -da -stats source_ir.ll` but nothing will print out.

Comment: The first one doesn't compute %div, it *is* %div. The instruction and its results cannot be separated in LLVM IR, they are one and the same. That which the third instruction uses is the first instruction. When the printout names %div, it names a dependency on that instruction. If you loop over the third instruction's operands() and test for equality against a pointer to the first, the test returns true for one operand. Similarly, if you loop over the first instruction's users(), one of the users is the third instruction.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation. So, are there any tools can get the number of analyzing the relation about that? I have some experience so I know the dependency like that may slow down the run time.

Comment: The relationship is explicitly stated. What analysis is needed?

Comment: Because I need to collect the relationship like that from the whole IR code. But I don't know very clearly about how much distance between two instruction could be a dependency. If there are tools, maybe it can tell everything I want to know.

Comment: Any distance is permitted. The distance doesn't matter (and passes are free to reorder many instructions anyway, subject to a couple of restrictions). The pointers in operands() always point directly to the instructions (and other values) on which an instruction depends, no matter where they are is on a printout, and pointers in users() always point directly to the instructions (or phi nodes) that use an instruction.

Comment: I have two IR code that the distance between first and third instructions are different. And I use `llc` to generate the assembly code. I found that the distances from the `div` and `mul` are different and the run time are different too. The run time of the close one is slower than the far one. So, I think that maybe the dependency let the code become slower.
Both of them are produced by the same C code.

Comment: I search for this issue and I found that maybe I can solve my problem by `def-use chain`. But I still stuck in the distances. I can't figure out how to define the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you're looking for is LLVM's [Data Dependency Graph](https://llvm.org/docs/DependenceGraphs/index.html#data-dependence-graph).  The 'Program Dependency Graph' also mentioned in the doc seems to have never been implemented - which is a shame, it would have provided better info. Both of them were mentioned first AFAIK in [this talk](https://youtu.be/3pRhvQi7Z10?t=3216).

Check [this LLVM test](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/unittests/Analysis/DDGTest.cpp) for usage examples.